# Cassandra nodetool status very slow

Tags: cassandra

I have a three node Cassandra cluster. Running nodetool status on two of the nodes returns within 1 seconds. Running it on the third node takes 30 seconds. Also connecting to this node via cqlsh is very slow whereas connecting to the other two nodes is instant. There is no activity on the node when doing this. Is there a way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I'm guessing not. On my systems (admittedly not fast) "nodetool help" uses 3 seconds of CPU time to run, status takes 5. Kinda crazy.

Comment: nodetool uses JMX, sometimes when cassandra is on heavy load takes a while to the JMX connector query the cassandra java proccess, I have the same issue with some prometheus exporters

Answer (score 0):

You can put hostname of node in /etc/hosts. It resolved for me.